# Displaying folder listings

Tags: google-drive

I can display a nice folder list for a Google Docs folder via a link like:

https://docs.google.com/folder/d/ID/preview

(where ID is replaced by the Google assigned id of the folder)

But when when I attempt to embed that on my web site in an iframe, I get a blank iframe. Is there a solution?

Comment: I note that other URLs ending in /preview, such as for a Google Doc word processing file, display fine in a frame. So why not folder listings?

Comment: That requires authentification. In Google Sites it would be do-able.

Comment: @Jacob Indeed. All the browsers that would want to do this for my application would already be logged in to Google, and have share permission on the folder. I can embed a Doc fine, why not a Folder? What is the security issues that permits one, but not the other?

Comment: Perhaps this is of use: https://sites.google.com/site/appsscriptexperiments/home/doc-list-viewer. See the item below this one as well.

Comment: Well, that might have possibility, if the App Script document (a spreadsheet I guess) can be embedded... A lot of overhead to do something that should be simple, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere along the line, I finally stumbled across some documentation or sample code that led me to this answer, which has been working a few months now:

https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=......#grid

(in the above example, replace the ...... with the id of the folder you wish to display)

Once you know the magic incantation, then you can find the documentation for it...

This isn't the official documentation for the feature, but it is a useful one:
https://sites.google.com/site/mori79/html-gadgets/how-tos/google-drive#TOC-Folders

I don't know where the official documentation for the feature is, nor if there is any.

Searching now, I find this answer in a stackoverflow question, although it hasn't been uprated (until I did): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367610/showing-documents-from-google-drive-on-webpage  And also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681974/how-to-embed-a-google-drive-folder-in-a-website

Comment: Your first link doesn't work

Comment: It isn't supposed to be an active link, but rather an example. Replace the ...... with the id of the folder you wish to display.